# Emulating MPEG-DASH for android

Tags: android, apache, mpeg-dash

I am working on the project mentioned. It is required to create an index file for media clips that are to be sent to android where the client downloads the media clip by parsing the index file. How can I put this index file (.mpd) on Apache server ? Also I am not clear with the concept how the media clips can be downloaded by android client parsing the index file? If anyone can please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with a PC not an Android, but I think they should be similar. You can use a standard Apache installation with a DASH dataset similar to the ones here http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=207 and of course you need a DASH client on your Android